# Error in rendering vue.js file using view instance new Vue()

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vuex, vue-router

I am working with vue.js, while rendering vue page i am getting below

> error "Cannot GET /KForm"

Below are my code in **main.js**

```
import * as componentBase from "@app/app_start"
import Form from "@views/Form/Form.vue"
import KForm from "@views/KForm/KForm"
const NotFound = { template: '<p>Page not found</p>' }

const routes = {
    '/': Form,
    '/recap': Recap,
    '/KForm': KForm   
}

const app = new Vue({   
    ...componentBase,
    data: {
        currentRoute: window.location.pathname
    },
    computed: {
        ViewComponent() {
            return routes[this.currentRoute] || NotFound
        }
    },
    render: h => h(this.ViewComponent) 
}).$mount("#app")
```

Comment: Do you check that file with name KForm exist in views/KForm directory?

Comment: Based on the import of `Form`, perhaps you need to change the import path from `KForm` to `"@views/KForm/KForm.vue"`. If that is not the issue, please tell us on what line you get the error

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what your webpack config is, but shouldn't the `KForm` import be this:

```
import KForm from "@views/KForm/KForm.vue"
                                     ^^^^
```

`currentRoute` is set to `window.location.pathname` *one time only* when the component is instantiated. When you click a link (or navigate directly from the browser's address bar) to, say `/KForm`, the window location changes and the browser tries to fetch the webpage at that new address just like in a traditional non-SPA webpage. This will fail unless the server responds to that URL.

To prevent the browser from doing this, you'll have to intercept `<a>` clicks and use the [history API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API) to change the window location without reloading the page, then change `currentRoute` accordingly.

Or better yet, just use [vue-router](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-router) which does all this for you. See [this](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/history-mode.html) for example server configurations for HTML5 history mode.